# Consecutive prime powers that are not prime

Tags: prime-numbers, perfect-powers

I am looking for consecutive entries $(a_k,a_{k+1})$ in the sequence of prime powers
$$(a_n)=(2,3,2^2,5,7,2^3,3^2,11,13,2^4,17,19,23,5^2,3^3,29,31,2^5\cdots)$$ such that neither $a_k$ nor $a_{k+1}$ are primes. Examples are $(2^3,3^2), (5^2,3^3), (3^7,13^3)$.  I realize this may be a very difficult problem, but I wonder how many have been found and what is known.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A025474

Comment: [A068435](https://oeis.org/A068435) (Consecutive prime powers without a prime between them).

Comment: Following the links provided in the comments, I have learned that only five such pairs are known to exist: $(2^3,3^2),(5^2,3^3),(11^2,5^3),(3^7,13^3),(181^2,2^{15})$.

Comment: Pillai's conjecture predicts large differences between perfect powers (apart from finite many exceptions) and this makes it likely that a prime is between such consecutive prime powers with a few expections. I do not know how far this has been checked, I guess upto at least $10^{12}$. I agree that the problem is very difficult and proofs are not to be expected.

Comment: Also the ratio must be less than 2 ( or 1.05 once big enough)

Comment: Course by PNT $\pi(p^k) =\frac{p^{k-1}}{k}\cdot \pi(p)$